# pass array value to outside of the value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Assume I declare an array in the class:

```
public array = [];
```

then I pass the value in the initializing method:

```
ngOnInit() {this.array = _.without(_.uniq(this.chartdata.map(x => x.ww)), null)}
```

But when I call this array in HTML file I found the array is still empty. How can I successfully pass value to this array?

```
<ng-select [items]="array" placeholder="WW" (change)="WWchange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedWW" multiple="true">
        </ng-select>
```

Comment: where you have used the array in Angular HTML ?

Comment: Show the values of `this.array`  in component and also show the html that you've used the array

Comment: It would be used as [items] = "array" @AmitVerma

Comment: check this line: `this.array = _.without(_.uniq(this.chartdata.map(x => x.ww)), null)` what is `chartdata` value? and what is the result of the line?